# Update Checkbox in Obj A, if its relevant record(from Lookup) got Selected in Obj B

Tags: custom-object, lookup, inputcheckboxes

I have Two Custom Objects , Obj A and Obj B, My requirement is i have to update checkbox true in Obj A once its relevant record(Lookup) got selected in Obj B.

Please suggest the solution and let me know if you want more clear.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: am trying to update through process builder, its not working

Comment: Post your effort with screenshots and where it is failing to get a better answer

Comment: Let me make sure I understand: When a checkbox on Obj B is True, set the checkbox on Obj A to True. Is that right?

Comment: ...or is it, when a record is selected in Obj A's lookup to Obj B, then set the checkbox on Obj A to True?

Comment: Hi Shane,Record is related to Obj B and checkbox will be in Obj B, When Obj B record is selected in Obj A(lookup to Obj B), Checkbox should become true...Am i Clear?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve it using the process builder. Create a process builder on ObjA and check that ObjB lookup is not null in the rule evaluation condition. Then update the ObjB record through update related record.

> "Select a record related to the ObjA" in the option and select the relevant field.

[image]